# How to center a LabelField with large font

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I need to horizontally center a LabelField using a vertical field manager. I also need to increase the size of the font of this LabelField. I find that, once I center it using FIELD_HCENTER, if I change the size of the font, it changes the position of the field.

This is the code

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
LabelField title = new LabelField("My Title",Field.FIELD_HCENTER) ;
title.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 18, Ui.UNITS_pt);
vfm.add(title);
```

(If I remove the third line, title.setFont, then the title is centered, otherwise, it's not). I need some help to get a solution for this. 
Any help is appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need only one `LabelField` to be centered horizontally on that `VerticalFieldManager`, or you will add more fields to that `VerticalFieldManager`?

Comment: I need to add three `LabelField`s in the `VerticalFieldManager`. Thanks. And all of them need to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom FieldManger by overriding `sublayout` method of `VerticalFieldManager`, which will place it's child in center. Following one is such an implementaion.

```
class CustomVerticalFieldManger extends VerticalFieldManager {
        private final int VERTICAL_GAP = 30;

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            int nFields = getFieldCount(), height = 0, xPosition, yPosition = 0;
            Field f;
            for (int i = 0; i < nFields; i++) {
                f = getField(i);
                layoutChild(f, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                height += f.getHeight();
                if (i != 0) {
                    height += VERTICAL_GAP;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nFields; i++) {
                f = getField(i);
                xPosition = (maxWidth - f.getWidth()) / 2;
                setPositionChild(f, xPosition, yPosition);
                yPosition += f.getHeight();
                if (i != nFields - 1) {
                    yPosition += VERTICAL_GAP;
                }
            }
            setExtent(maxWidth, height);
        }
    }
```

***Usage***

```
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    private LabelField lblOne, lblTwo, lblThree;

    public MyScreen() {
        CustomVerticalFieldManger cvfm = new CustomVerticalFieldManger();
        cvfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.AQUA));

        lblOne = new LabelField("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        lblTwo = new LabelField("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        lblThree = new LabelField("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");

        cvfm.add(lblOne);
        cvfm.add(lblTwo);
        cvfm.add(lblThree);

        add(cvfm);

        changeFont();
    }

    private int fontSize = 5;

    private void changeFont() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (fontSize == 50) {
                            fontSize = 5;
                        }
                        lblOne.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,
                                fontSize));
                        lblTwo.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,
                                fontSize + 2));
                        lblThree.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,
                                fontSize + 4));
                        fontSize += 6;
                        updateLayout();
                        invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 500, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine. `height` seems to be an unused variable. Did you intend to use it for something?

Comment: Yes, `height` is an important variable, it is the final height of the Manager. It supposed to be the second parameter of the `setExtent()`, but in this case both the value of `yPosition` and `height` are same, and using `yPosition` instead of `height` didn't create any problem. You can edit this answer, and replace `setExtent(maxWidth, yPosition);` with `setExtent(maxWidth, height);`